# django model filter date time from midnight

Tags: django, filter, timezone

I used django model filter with date.

Origin data has time of Africa/Abidjan(UTC+00:00) and I save this data on my database.

I set timezone about Asia/Seoul(UTC+09:00)and it's save well in my database.

But I filter data with time_range=[2015-11-15, 2015-11-16], I got data about from 15 o'clock to 14 o'clock. I want to get data from 0 o'clock to 23 o'clock.

How can I get this? I do this url, but it doesn't work well.

```
class Post(models.Model):
    created_time = models.DateTimeField()
```

If I have a model like post, and I get date from user.

```
input_date = '2015-11-16' (from user)
from_date = datetime.strptime(input_date, '%Y-%m-%d').date()
to_date = from_date + datetime.timedelta(days=1)
posts = Post.objects.filter(created_time__range=[from_date, to_date])
```

I used upper code and got data from 2015-11-15 15:00:00 to 2015-11-16 14:00:00.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `from_date = datetime.strptime(input_date, '%Y-%m-%d')` (without `.date()`), maybe it requires `datetime` instead of `date` object.